# Outlook 2010 - VBA MsgBox if more then 10 unread elements mails

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to start Outlook, then Outlook should only show ALL mailboxes, which have also unread emails.

At the moment, my VBA-Script expand all my mailbox folders / accounts.
But the list is unfortunately too long, now.

I am looking for a way to check unread elements.
I have tried it with a simple `MsgBox`, but does not work.

```
    Private Sub Application_Startup()
    'Folder-Variable definieren
    Dim objFolderIMAP01 As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objFolderIMAP02 As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objFolderIMAP03 As Outlook.Folder

    'IMAP-Folder zuweisen (hier in Klammern mit Anführungszeichen den Namen der IMAP-Datendatei eintragen)
    Set objFolderIMAP01 = Outlook.Session.Folders("MailBox1")
    Set objFolderIMAP02 = Outlook.Session.Folders("MailBox2")
    Set objFolderIMAP03 = Outlook.Session.Folders("MailBox3")

    'Alle Unterordner selektieren (und damit aufklappen)
    Call selectAllFolderRec(objFolderIMAP01)
    Call selectAllFolderRec(objFolderIMAP02)
    Call selectAllFolderRec(objFolderIMAP03)

    'Posteingang als Startordnder auswählen
    Call Outlook.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder(objFolderIMAP01.Folders("Posteingang"))
    Call Outlook.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder(objFolderIMAP02.Folders("Posteingang"))
    Call Outlook.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder(objFolderIMAP03.Folders("Posteingang"))

    'Info wenn mehr als 10 Emails ungelesen
    If objFolderIMAP01.UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Mailbox 1 ist voll!"
    End If
    If objFolderIMAP01.UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Mailbox 2 ist voll!"
    End If
    If objFolderIMAP01.UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Mailbox 3 ist voll!"
    End If
End Sub

Sub selectAllFolderRec(objFolder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim bolSkipSelect As Boolean
    bolSkipSelect = False
    For lngCounter = 1 To objFolder.Folders.Count
        If objFolder.Folders(lngCounter).Folders.Count > 0 And objFolder.Folders(lngCounter).Folders.UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
            Call selectAllFolderRec(objFolder.Folders(lngCounter))
          Else
            If bolSkipSelect = False Then
                Call Outlook.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder(objFolder.Folders(lngCounter))
                bolSkipSelect = True
            End If
        End If
    Next lngCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: What does 'not work' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: I'm little confused, so you want to open Outlook and only see accounts that have `unread items` ? and then what?

Comment: I have tried this:         `If objFolderIMAP01.UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Mailbox " & objFolderIMAP01 & " ist voll!" & " (" & objFolderIMAP01.UnReadItemCount & ")"
        End If` But it counts always 0 unread items.

Comment: `Call Outlook.ActiveExplorer.SelectFolder` can you post that?

Comment: Update the question, replacing "but does not work" with the results of running the code. If there is an error state what it is and indicate the line that is highlighted when the error occurs.

Comment: The script is mostly not mine. But I just see that this IF query could be rebuilt. Has anyone an idea how to extend the query for unread emails here? (I have edited the code, look at my question.)

I tried this, but it stopped for debugging, this is maybay incorrect: objFolder.Folders(lngCounter).Folders.UnReadItemCount

Answer (score 0):

The folder called "MailBox1" will not have mail.

If you want to check for unread mail in the inbox of Mailbox1 you have to specify `objFolderIMAP01.Folders("Posteingang")`.

```
'Info wenn mehr als 10 Emails ungelesen
'Info if more than 10 mails unread
If objFolderIMAP01.Folders("Posteingang").UnReadItemCount > 10 Then
    MsgBox "Inbox of Mailbox 1 is full! - Posteingang von Mailbox 1 ist voll!"
End If
```